# Closing vertical spacing around figure in LaTeX

Tags: overleaf, wrapfigure

These are the packages I'm using:

```
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
% use times new roman for main text
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig, framed, caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
% use cambria for math
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{[Cambria-Math.ttf]}
% single line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing
```

This is the code I'm using to input my figure. [image: My figure with too much vertical buffer space]

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{framed}
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.5}{\input{Dukes}}
        \caption{Corresponding graphs to combinatorial objects.}
        \label{fig:my_label}
\end{framed}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Is there a way to decrease the amount of space above and below my figure?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: wrapfig has an optional argument to say how many lines to cut in

Comment: Any news? Does any of received answers solve your problem. If yes, please accept it and by this inform audience here, that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Also You can do this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian,ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{wrapfig, framed, caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{framed}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a.png}
\caption{Corresponding graphs to combinatorial objects.}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{framed}
\vspace{-20pt}%<----- added
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can define as option of `wrapfigure` a number of text rows spanned by it and rise it for height of `2ex` that will aligned with top oof the first text line:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[13]{l}{0.5\textwidth} % <---
\vspace{-2ex} % <---
    \begin{framed}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Corresponding graphs to combinatorial objects.}
\label{fig:my_label}
    \end{framed}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]